# Button Style performance hit

Tags: wpf, performance, button, styles, contenttemplate

I have a usecase to show nearly 10000 items in a WPF usercontrol. I am using ItemsControl and each item is represented by a button (items a simple clickable text). I have defined a style for button in usercontrol resources.

Things work fine till I have more than 5000 items in my list then UI paint starts to slow down- 10000 items takes nearly 3+ minutes to be displayed.

If I move the style from resources to Button.Style then also it take 2.5 mins to displays the items.

If I remove the style completely, I see no noticeable delay.The only reason to use Button style is to give its ContentPresenter's Border (named as Chrome in below code) the same background as button, which is otherwise Gray.

Please let me know how can I use styles efficiently without incurring a Performance hit or how can I paint the ContentPresenter Border's Background as same color as Button (transparent would work somehow).

Here is the code sample:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Property=Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Name="Grid1" Margin="5,5,5,5">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="5,0,0,0">
        <Border Name="Border1"  Margin="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2">
                <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl1" ItemsSource="{Binding LargeItems}" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Columns}" Rows="{Binding Rows}"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Name="Border1" Background="{Binding BorderBkg}" 
                                    BorderThickness="1" Padding="{Binding PaddingVal}">
                                <Button Name="MyButton" Content="{Binding Label}"                            
                                        Background="{Binding Background}"    
                                        Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                        Margin="0"
                                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}"
                                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.ButtonAction}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                </Button>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
        </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Thanks,

RDV

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no data virtualization implemented in your ItemControl. You can implement the virtualization by adding 
VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
in your ItemsControl and see the performance difference.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs shijeesh, unfortunately I have to display all 10,000 items together hence VirtualizingPanel is not helping me. I did try it, but rendering is slow ~3 mins for 10,000 items.